# how do i use a class object as a model for a page in ionic framework

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have a class object for a settings page eg.

```
export class SystemSettingsObject{

Settings1: number,
Settings2: boolean

}
```

How do I use that as a model for my settings page?

In my settings.ts file(.ts file for the view) I have this:

```
model : SystemSettingsObject

constructor(private systemsettings: SystemSettingsProvider){
 this.model = systemsettings.GetSystemSettings(); // this returns the systemSettingsobject, populated with data
}
```

If I had to use this model in a page would it just be a matter of saying, [(NgModel)] = "model.Settings1" on an input field?

I also keep getting errors saying cannot initialize Settings1 as null

So I'm not too sure how to fix this, any advice.

Thanks

Comment: It's recommended that you name your variables in **lower camel case** to distinguish it from class names.

Comment: I can see an issue with the code you've shown, is `systemSettings` initialized prior to being passed into the constructor? And does the function `GetSystemSettings()` return an instance of `SystemSettingsObject`? I assume it does otherwise the compiler would moan.